# blazor StateHasChanged not working in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app.  I dynamically add a custom control (which I created in a Razor Class Library) to my page, like this:

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row ">
       <div class="col-12">
          <label>@p_section.question</label>
       </div>
    </div>
   @foreach (object new_control_model in p_section.list_of_control_models)
    {         
         DisaggregateControlModel new_disag_model = (DisaggregateControlModel)new_control_model;                                                
         <DisaggregateControl @ref="myComponents[new_disag_model.id]" model="new_disag_model">
         </DisaggregateControl>                                                
    }
</div>
```

This add the control to my dictionary, which I can access.

```
@code {
   private Dictionary<string, object> myComponents = new Dictionary<string, object>();  
   
}
```

In the custom control, I have a method that sets a bool, which allows me to display or hide a Div.  In the web component that has this code, I want to iterate over all the objects in myComponents and either turn on or off the div display.  I do  that like this:

```
foreach (string id in some_list_of_ids){
   //find the object in myComponents list
   object found_obj = myComponents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == id).Value;
   //cast to my custom control
   DisaggregateControl myControl = (DisaggregateControl)found_obj;
   // based on property, determine if I should show the div or not
   if(myControl.some_vale >0){
      //show
      myControl.showDiv(true);
   }else{
     myControl.showDiv(false);
  }
}
//updated all the controls, so update the page
StateHasChanged();
```

If I debug and walk through, I can see that the code works.  The correct divs are shown/hidden.  Until the code reaches StateHasChanged(), and then all the divs are hidden.  If I remove StateHasChanged then the code also does not work (the divs are not shown, when they should be).

I am not sure what the issue is or how to best handle this?

Comment: Start by adding a `@key` so Blazor can track the component instances `<DisaggregateControl @key=new_disag_model.id @ref="myComponents[new_disag_model.id]"`

Comment: @MisterMagoo Thanks for the suggestion.  I added the key, but that has not made a difference.

Comment: Does the showDiv method work if you just have one DisaggregateControl not in a loop?

Comment: @MisterMagoo Turns out that it was an issue with my variable.  In the custom library, I showed/hid the div by setting a bool value.  But, I inadvertently made the bool static.  Once I changed that, it worked fine.  I assume because the variable was static, once I changed it for one control, it got changed for all controls.  Thanks for helping me find the issue!

Comment: Hi Jason, would you please add that as an answer and close out the question.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that it was an issue with my variable. In the custom library, I showed/hid the div by setting a bool value. But, I inadvertently made the bool static. Once I changed that, it worked fine. I assume because the variable was static, once I changed it for one control, it got changed for all controls.